GNU Make: plain dashes are sometimes suppressed in multi-line variables
I'm trying to define with GNU Make v4.4.1 a multi-line variable for a YAML file header, like:
#foo
---

The idea is to echo the header to a file inside a recipe. For a reason unknown to me, the dashes are stripped off in some cases.
Here's a MWE:
.ONESHELL:

define dashes
# dashes below stripped off
---
endef

define dashes_hex
# hex dashes below kept
\x2d\x2d\x2d
endef

define only_dashes
---
endef

define dashes_first
---
# dashes above kept
endef

.PHONY: a b c d

a:
    @echo -e "a>$(dashes)<"

b:
    @echo -e "b>$(dashes_hex)<"

c:
    @echo -e "c>$(only_dashes)<"

d:
    @echo -e "d>$(dashes_first)<"


Test:
$ make a b c d
a># dashes below stripped off
<
b># hex dashes below kept
---<
c>---<
d>---
# dashes above kept<

As you can see:

case b) a workaround is to use the corresponding HEX value instead of the plain dash character,
case c) a single line of plain dashes is correctly printed,
case d) plain dashes on the first line are correctly printed.

What's so special with plain dashes and Make?
Why cases c and d have correct outcome?

Aside the point of the question, but your code will be more portable if you avoid echo in general and echo -e in particular. See the [UNIX.se] question Why is printf better than echo?; that's particularly important when you aren't forcing which shell make invokes so your code needs to be compatible with whichever /bin/sh the system running your makefile happens to provide.

As @MadScientist pointed out, with .ONESHELL, leading dashes are treated as special characters.

Yes, obviously -- I upvoted that answer when it was written yesterday. Doesn't detract from the validity of the comment.

First, you should never use @ to prefix your lines when you're trying to debug a makefile.  Seeing the command that make is invoking is critical to understanding the behavior.
Next, You should never use echo -e in a makefile that needs to be portable.  In fact, the only thing echo can do in a portable shell script is print simple strings: there are no standardized options to echo.  Some versions support -e, some do not.
If you need to print formatted output, you should use the printf program instead to be portable.
Third, if you want to know what the values of variables are in GNU Make, use the info function to print them rather than a recipe; this lets you know what the value is without the shell interfering.  If you add:
$(info dashes:|$(dashes)|)
$(info dashes_hex:|$(dashes_hex)|)
$(info only_dashes:|$(only_dashes)|)
$(info dashes_first:|$(dashes_first)|)

You'll see that make has the correct/expected content for every variable:
dashes:|# dashes below stripped off
---|
dashes_hex:|# hex dashes below kept
\x2d\x2d\x2d|
only_dashes:|---|
dashes_first:|---
# dashes above kept|

This means that the problem is not that the variable value is wrong, but rather in the creation or run of the recipe.
I believe the problem is that .ONESHELL is not really designed to handle the situation you are creating.  If you use a variable that contains newlines, make considers that every line in the recipe is a separate "command".  As such, it will check each line to see if it begins with a @ or a - and if so, they will be stripped.  See this paragraph in the documentation:

As a special feature, if SHELL is determined to be a POSIX-style shell, the special prefix characters in “internal” recipe lines will be removed before the recipe is processed. This feature is intended to allow existing makefiles to add the .ONESHELL special target and still run properly without extensive modifications. Since the special prefix characters are not legal at the beginning of a line in a POSIX shell script this is not a loss in functionality.

Unfortunately it looks like you've discovered a loophole where the final sentence in this paragraph is not actually true.
To work around this you need to find a way to make it so that the dashes are not the first thing on the line.  Here's a trick that works:
define dashes
# dashes below stripped off
$$empty---
endef

a:
        printf "a>$(dashes)<\n";

The $$empty will expand to $empty, which is a shell variable that is not set, so the shell will expand it to the empty string, and printf outputs:
a># dashes below stripped off
---<


So, basically I failed at the basic principles of makefile writing and Make finally told me that the hard way ^^ Now it's time to review tons of badly written makefiles.

Would that documentation loophole warrant a bug report?

Yes, that would be good.  I'm not sure the best way to handle this.  I'm thinking the best thing might be to provide a way to declare which shells are "POSIX" and which are not, rather than the built-in heuristic make uses today.  That would allow people to disable the special handling make tries to do, without forcing people to create a "fake shell".  Or, on the other hand, declare some "other shell" is really a POSIX-ish shell even though it doesn't look like it.
